# Show that $\det(AB-BA) × \det(AC-CA) \geq 0$ if $A^2 = -BC$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, matrix-decomposition, characteristic-polynomial

We have $A,B,C$ three $n×n$ matrices with real entries. We know that
$$
  A^2 = -BC
$$
and we want to show that
$$
  \det(AB-BA) × \det(AC-CA) \geq 0 \,.
$$

We can easily show that for $n=2k$ we have $\det(B) × \det(C) \geq 0$, and for $n = 2k + 1$ we have $\det(B) × \det(C) \leq0$. Then for $n = 2k$ we can expand $\det(AB-BA)$ like
$$
  2 × \det(A) × \det(B) - c_1 + c_2 - c_3 + c_4 - \dotsb +c_{n-2} - c_{n-1}
$$
and expand $\det(AC-CA)$ like
$$
  2 × \det(A) × \det(C) - d_1 + d_2 - d_3 + d_4 - \dotsb + d_{n-2} - d_{n-1} \,.
$$
For $n = 2k + 1$, we can expand $\det(AB - BA)$ like
$$
  c_1 - c_2 + c_3 - c_4 + \dotsb + c_{n-2} - c_{n-1}
$$
and $\det(AC - CA)$ like
$$
  d_1 - d_2 + d_3 - d_4 + \dotsb + d_{n-2} - d_{n-1} \,.
$$
If we multiply these two expanded forms in every case $n = 2k$ and $n = 2k+1$, then we get an ugly answer and I don’t know we can check the sign like that. I am now stuck. Maybe we need to use eigenvalues? Please someone help me solve this problem.

Comment: your attempt is very unclear. What are $c_i$ and $d_i's ?$ How exactly are you doing this "expansion" ?

Comment: $det(A+xB)$ expansion formula with Viete relations.

Comment: Is there a connection with [your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4604429/305862) asked an hour before this one ? In both cases, they deal with commutators.

Comment: Yes I was thinking to rewrite de expansion of det(AB-BA) and det(AC-CA) in a nicer form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $A^2+BC=0$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\quad\det(AB-BA)\det(AC-CA)\\
&=\det\pmatrix{AB-BA&0\\ A^2+CB&AC-CA}\\
&=\det\left[\pmatrix{A&-B\\ C&A}\pmatrix{B&-A\\ A&C}\right]\\
&=\det\left[\pmatrix{A&-B\\ C&A}\pmatrix{-I&0\\ 0&I}\pmatrix{A&-B\\ C&A}\pmatrix{0&I\\ I&0}\right]\\
&=\det\pmatrix{A&-B\\ C&A}\times(-1)^n\times\det\pmatrix{A&-B\\ C&A}\times(-1)^n\\
&=\det\pmatrix{A&-B\\ C&A}^2\ge0.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: This looks so clean. Did you use matrices on blocks? ( I did not learn it but that looks interesting) thanks

Comment: @StefanSolomon You only need to know how to do blockwise matrix multiplication here. There isn't anything advanced.

Comment: but why is $CB+A^2 = 0$ ?

Comment: @dezdichado You are right. That was a mistake.

Comment: yeah now I think this is complete and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Did you edit your solution? There is still the mistake A^2+CB=0

Comment: @StefanSolomon No, I didn't claim that $A^2+CB=0$ in the new edit. I only used the fact that the determinant of a block lower triangular matrix is the product of determinants of its diagonal sub-blocks.

Comment: Oh ok so the solution is right thanks

Answer (score 4):

Since $-A^3 = ABC = BCA,$ I think a cute solution is as follows:
$$\det\left((AB-BA)CB(AC-CA)\right) = \det\left((ABC-BAC)(BAC-BCA)\right) = \det((-A^3-BAC)(BAC+A^3)) = (-1)^n\det(A^3+BAC)^2.$$
But the LHS is just:
$$\det\left((AB-BA)CB(AC-CA)\right) = (-1)^n\det(AB-BA)\det(AC-CA)\det(A^2) = $$
so the potential minus sign will cancel and we are done.

**EDIT:** Just so people know, this answer is incomplete as the case $\det A = 0$ is not covered. It was simply meant to be an alternative to the corresponding part of answer below, which is complete with the limiting argument.

Furthermore, the now-deleted solution by user1551 can be modified - even though $A^2+CB$ is not zero necessarily, it does not alter the block matrix manipulation since we still have:
$$\det\begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ B & D \end{pmatrix} = \det A\det D$$
assuming the dimensions conform. But since the answer is deleted, I have no way of adding this modification.

Comment: How do you deal with the case if $\text{det}(A) = 0$? In this case both sides are $0$.

Comment: yeah I had meant to say this was an alternative to your solution's non-degenerate part. I don't see how the singular case will be handled purely with some simple algebraic manipulation

Comment: @dezdichado Nice. Is there a proof proceeding along user1551's idea (manipulating block matrices)?

Comment: @RiverLi, I think his solution is good if we just replace that lower left $0$ by $A^2+CB$:
$$\dots\det\begin{pmatrix}AB-BA & 0 \\ A^2+CB & AC-CA\end{pmatrix} = \dots$$
since the simplification would still hold.

Comment: @dezdichado Can we reach a square of determinant like what user1551's last line?

Comment: @RiverLi yes, the only thing changes is the second line which is what I wrote above.

Comment: @dezdichado So there is no mistake in user1551's proof?

Comment: @RiverLi, with this rectification I think the proof is fine. He had previously inadvertently assumed $CB+A^2 = 0$ but it turns out it was not needed.

Comment: @dezdichado Yes, thanks.

Comment: @dezdichado Thanks a lot! It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: this is most likely not the intended / easiest solution. I wrote it here because it is a very general trick that can be applied to a variety of similar matrix questions.

Step 1: Solve the problem when the matrices involved are invertible.

Suppose $A, B, C$ are invertible. In this case, we have $B = -A^2C^{-1}$, so
$$AB - BA = - A^3C^{-1} + A^2C^{-1}A = A^2C^{-1}(AC - CA)C^{-1}.$$
So we have
$$\text{det}(AB - BA) = \text{det}(A)^2 \text{det}(C)^{-2}\text{det}(AC - CA)$$
Thus $\text{det}(AB - BA)$ and $\text{det}(AC - CA)$ have the same sign.

Step 2: Approximate non-invertible matrices by invertible matrices.

We need the following general lemma.

**Lemma**: If $A = BC$, and a sequence of invertible matrices $\{A_i\}$ converges to $A$, then there exists sequences of invertible matrices $\{B_i\}$, $\{C_i\}$ converging to $B$, $C$ respectively such that $A_i = B_iC_i$.

To prove the lemma, one can reduce to the case when $B$ is diagonal by say LR-decomposition, in which case one can let $B_i$ be diagonal as well. Anyway the lemma should intuitively be true.

To apply this lemma to this problem, let $\{A_i\}$ be a sequence of invertible matrices converging to $A$. Then there exists sequences of invertible matrices $\{B_i\}$ and $\{C_i\}$ converging to $B, C$ respectively, such that $A_i^2 = -B_iC_i$. By step 1, we have
$$\text{det}(A_i B_i - B_i A_i)\text{det}(A_i C_i - C_i A_i) \geq 0.$$
Taking the limit $i \to \infty$ gives the desired result
$$\text{det}(A B - B A)\text{det}(A C - C A) \geq 0.$$

Comment: Nice argument. To nitpick,  it's $C = -B^{-1}A^2$ but just swapping $B\leftrightarrow C$ should fix it.

Comment: Thank you for catching the error! I corrected it.

Comment: Interesting I did not knew about this trick and this lemma

Comment: @ShengtongZhang: It is possible that your lemma is correct. However, your hint of a proof is not clear how to implement it. In general, if we chose  invertible $A_i$ and $B_i$ converging to $A$ and $B$ respectively, then $C_i=B_i^{-1}A_i$. Of course, we can assume that $C_i$ converges to, say, the matrix $C'$. We have $BC=BC'$. It does not follow that $C=C'$.

Comment: The point of the lemma is that we can simultaneously guarantee $A_i = B_iC_i$, $B_i \to B$ and $C_i \to C$ at the same time. Indeed, it is not true that the first and second implies the third.